# Javascript pick out peak numbers from groups of highs in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

Hard to describe it with the title but it should be clear from the description and code here. I'm trying to pick out the highest number out of an array from a group of peaks, and then go onto the next group and get the next peak number from the next group of highs.

So for example in this array:

```
const arr = [939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424, 506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915, 1276, 1532, 1359, 985, 2182, 2407, 2103, 2392, 2294, 765, 1195, 1537, 1409, 858, 1971, 2214, 1311, 1326, 1383, 1231, 1141]
```

I want to pick out `2462` from the first group of peaks at roughly `1037, 2279, 2462, 2193` and then move on to pick out `2456` from the next group at around `506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915`. The locations of the groups are not known, it's a matter of finding them and picking one highest number from each group.

This is the function I have at the moment but it doesn't work a 100% and doesn't work with certain arrays.

```
let currHigh = 0, store = [], limit = 2100;
for (let s = 0; s < arr.length; s++) {
    if (arr[s] > limit && currHigh === 0) {
        currHigh = arr[s]
    } else if (arr[s] > limit && arr[s] > currHigh) {
        currHigh = arr[s];
    } else if (arr[s] < currHigh) {
        if (arr[s] < limit) {
            store.push(currHigh); currHigh = 0;
        }
    }
}
console.log(store)
```

The highs are always pretty similar (2000+) and the locations of the number groups are similar but not the same so I can't really rely on that.

So the first array and expected/desired output would be:

```
const arr = [939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424, 506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915, 1276, 1532, 1359, 985, 2182, 2407, 2103, 2392, 2294, 765, 1195, 1537, 1409, 858, 1971, 2214, 1311, 1326, 1383, 1231, 1141]

Outputted Peaks: [2462, 2456, 2407, 2294, 2214]
```

And another example array with expected/desired output:

```
const arr =  [1365, 1324, 1013, 1220, 1259, 2204, 2212, 1938, 1882, 1545, 1236, 2090, 2614, 1949, 1307, 1628, 1780, 1263, 1184, 2184, 1411, 1306, 2010, 2057, 1339, 1624, 2480, 2575, 2425, 2617, 2479, 1929, 1805, 1869, 1341, 1104, 2195, 1661, 1174, 1447, 1761, 1362, 1430]

Outputted Peaks: [2212, 2614, 2184, 2480, 2617, 2195]
```

EDIT: To save some confusion, imagine if you were to take the values in the array given and plot them on a graph, there would be several peaks in the graph spaced apart. I need a function that gets those peaks. Finding the groups is just one way of finding the peaks. They would be like mini mountains. So you wouldn't want to get a high number that is on the 'side of the mountain' for example.

EDIT: Attaching image to explain peaks. High numbers right next to another high number is not a peak, only the highest number in a small group of adjacent numbers is a peak.
[image]

Final EDIT: This graph illustrates it best since it's difficult to imagine a graph just looking at the array:

https://jsbin.com/nicuciquru/1/edit?js,output

So what I would need here are the peaks `[1301, 1380, 2462, 2456, 1532, 2407, 2492, 1537, 2214, 1383]` which you can see on the graph. Then from there these peaks can be filtered  easily with a threshold to for example eliminate any peaks below 2000.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194915/discussion-on-question-by-hasen-javascript-pick-out-peak-numbers-from-groups-of).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that finds *all* the peaks in your sample array:

```
    const chart = [939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424, 506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915, 1276, 1532, 1359, 985, 2182, 2407, 2103, 2392, 2294, 765, 1195, 1537, 1409, 858, 1971, 2214, 1311, 1326, 1383, 1231, 1141]

    const findPeaks = chart => chart.reduce((agg, current, i) => {
        const prev = chart[i - 1];
        const next = chart[i + 1];

        return current > prev && current > next ? [...agg, current] : agg;
    }, []);

    const peaks = findPeaks(chart);

    console.log('peaks', peaks);
```

This logs: `[1301, 1380, 2462, 2456, 1532, 2407, 2392, 1537, 2214, 1383]`

This doesn't match the expected output from your question, but it does give an accurate answer to "what are the peaks".

In this case a "peak" is defined as any number who's predecessor and successor are both lower than itself. i.e. [1, 100, 1] gives 100. [1, 2, 3, 100, 3, 2, 100, 1] gives [100, 100]

**Update**

Based on your feedback, here's a function that requires a peak to have a distance of 2 on *each* side. The result is still not the same as in your question but this conforms to the newly expressed criteria:

```
const findPeaks = chart => chart.reduce((agg, current, i) => {
        const twoBack = chart[i - 2];
        const prev = chart[i - 1];
        const next = chart[i + 1];
        const twoForward = chart[i + 2];

        return (twoBack < prev && prev < current) && (current > next  && next > twoForward ) 
        ? [...agg, current] 
        : agg;
    }, []);
```

For the above input, this produces:

`[2462, 2456, 1532, 1537, 1383]`

**Update 2**

Here's a version of the code that finds *all* the peaks, figures out the median, and returns all peaks greater than the median. This is the closest result to what you're asking for in your question:

```
const findPeaks = chart => {

    const peaks = chart.reduce((agg, current, i) => {
    const twoBack = chart[i - 2];
    const prev = chart[i - 1];
    const next = chart[i + 1];
    const twoForward = chart[i + 2];

    return (prev < current) && (current > next) 
    ? [...agg, current] 
    : agg;
    }, []);

    const mean = peaks.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / peaks.length;

    return peaks.filter(peak => peak > mean);
}
```

The output of this is:

`[2462, 2456, 2407, 2392, 2214]`

Comment: 2462, 2456...? How can they be peaks if they're next to each other? I'll see if I can attach an image to my question.

Comment: 2462 is a peak of `939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193`. i.e. the numbers either side of it are lower. 2456 comes from `2411, 2456, 2295`, again, the numbers either side of it are lower than it (i.e. it's a peak).

Comment: Do you want the peaks to be of a minimum size or something?

Comment: 2462 will plot as a peak on a graph, but 2456 is the side of the peak made by 2462. You have to have at least one number between each one to make a peak.

Comment: You basically have a 'hill' plotted by the numbers 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424 for example. With 2462 being at the summit.

Comment: You don't have to have a number between each one, but it seems like you're saying that's your definition of a peak, which is fine.

Comment: I think I'm reading your data wrong, yes your peaks are correct, 2462 and 2456 are not next to each other, I was looking at your output instead of the original array. You do indeed have at least one number between each one. All that your code needs is to adjust the threshold so any numbers above 2100 for example.

Comment: See my update at the bottom of my answer. It's still not what you seem to want, but I think this process is helping to clarify your question.

Comment: Ok, is there a threshold of 2100 in there? Surely 1532 shouldn't be there if it is. My code above gets `[2462, 2456, 2407, 2214]` from there with a 2100 threshold. I guess it's not easy to detect these peaks lol.

Comment: Peaks are easy to find if we know what you mean by "peak". It seems like you don't actually want the tip of each triangle. I'm trying to understand your criteria. Can you be clearer?

Comment: I updated my question againn using the graph provided by Randy. Please check that at the end of the question and it will be as clear as an unmuddied lake. :)

Comment: Sure, but where does your threshold come from? How are you determining it?

Comment: The threshold is not important, it's just arbitrary for all intents and purposes. All that matters for now is to get the peaks which are clearly from the graph `[1301, 1380, 2462, 2456, 1532, 2407, 2492, 1537, 2214, 1383]`.

Comment: @Hasen Please see my final update. This takes the mean value and filters the peaks.

Comment: @Hasen Are you kidding me? :D This is the answer I gave in the very first place! The result of my first function is `[1301, 1380, 2462, 2456, 1532, 2407, 2492, 1537, 2214, 1383]`

Comment: The threshold is just the height of the mountains you want to get. It can be altered as necessary. Not sure if your code currently will get all those peaks I listed above? That's the first step, and the hardest part.

Comment: That was the easy part. You said it wasn’t right but now you’re saying it is. Haha

Comment: Oh yeah you're right, I was looking at your update below it which I didn't quite get. Surely with a threshold of 2100 the updated output should have been [2462, 2456, 2407, 2392, 2214] then and not [2462, 2456, 1532, 1537, 1383] ? I was too preoccupied with that to notice you had the right answer.

Comment: That and the 200,000 billion comments saying they didn't get it kept me preoccupied from seeing you had the right answer all along. It seems at least you did get it all along and even got the right answer lol. Ironically I didn't see it.

The reason your answer doesn't match mine is because you didn't have the `limit = 2100` that I had in my code above. :)

I'll check if it works with the second array. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without defining more precisely the desired output (e.g. what is considered a group?), here's a simplistic algorithm:

1) split the array into "low" and "high" sequences.

- E.g. `[1, 10000, 100, 101, 20000, 20050, 30, 10, 2]` => `[1], [10000], [100, 101], [20000, 20050], [30, 10, 2]`.

2) Return the max of each high sequence.

```js
let peaks = arr => {
 let isHigh = a => a >= 2000;
 let isLow = a => !isHigh(a);

 let groups = [];
 while (arr.length && arr.some(isHigh)) {
  arr.splice(0, arr.findIndex(isHigh));
  groups.push(arr.splice(0, arr.findIndex(isLow)));
 }

 return groups.map(group => Math.max(...group));
};


const arr = [939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424, 506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915, 1276, 1532, 1359, 985, 2182, 2407, 2103, 2392, 2294, 765, 1195, 1537, 1409, 858, 1971, 2214, 1311, 1326, 1383, 1231, 1141];
console.log(peaks(arr));

const arr2 = [1365, 1324, 1013, 1220, 1259, 2204, 2212, 1938, 1882, 1545, 1236, 2090, 2614, 1949, 1307, 1628, 1780, 1263, 1184, 2184, 1411, 1306, 2010, 2057, 1339, 1624, 2480, 2575, 2425, 2617, 2479, 1929, 1805, 1869, 1341, 1104, 2195, 1661, 1174, 1447, 1761, 1362, 1430];
console.log(peaks(arr2));
```

Comment: This is my comment to hasen above: _Given the image you posted in your question, the "not peaks" are clear, but how do you determine that the left "peak" is actually a "peak" and not a "not peak" - that is the part you are not making clear._ - You arbitrarily chose any peak above 2000 - that looks like what the OP wants, but has still not clarified.  Ref to this for a visual an include link in your answer aif you wnat to: https://jsbin.com/novimifada/edit?js,output

Comment: @Randy Casburn I think perhaps the word 'peak' is confusing you. Better to think of it as mountains. You can't look at 3,5,6,2 and say 3, 5 and 6 are mountains because they certainly wouldn't draw a mountain shape on a graph. You have to have at least three numbers to make a mountain because it's a triangle. So for example 1,3,1, makes a mountain of which 3 is the peak of it. Or 1,3,5,4,2,1 is a mountain where 5 is the peak of it.

Comment: @Randy Casburn Ok that link works for me now...looks like a picture of a mountain range. Not sure what's wrong with this? Aren't the peaks of each mountain easy to see? At least visually, if not to get with code.

Comment: I'm not confused - and sure its easy to see that 1301 and 1380 are peaks - now dispute that.

Comment: @Hasen The answer I gave showed the tip of every triangle. Then you said the triangles have to be a certain size before they count, otherwise they're "hills". Can you give a fuller more specific definition of what you want included? :)

Comment: @Randy Casburn "and sure its easy to see that 1301 and 1380 are peaks - now dispute that" Why do I want to dispute that?

Comment: From your own words in your qeustion: _**Outputted Peaks: [2462, 2456, 2407, 2294, 2214]**_ - because 1301 and 1380, while peaks on a line chart (which you also referred to) are NOT in the your list of expected results! You have not defined the problem space well enough for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @Jamie Dixon Check Randy's link, it's very illustrative. Those peaks are what we need to get. So 1301, 1380, 2462, 2456, 1532, 2407, 2492, 1537, 2214 and probably 1383 too I guess. Then a filter by theshold will get rid of values below 2000 or whatever if necessary.

Comment: @Randy Casburn Those peaks can surely be easily filters out by a threshold? Start by getting 1301, 1380, 2462, 2456, 1532, 2407, 2492, 1537, 2214,1383. That is the hardest part.

Comment: @Hasen - no, it is quest easy.  Now that you _see_ what we've been trying to tell you, will you PLEASE go back and edit the question to make it clearer for everyone in the future. StackOverflow is about capturing GOOD questions for the long term. The quality of this qeustion is terrible as currently written.

Comment: @Randy Casburn if you check my function it has a limit of 2100 which filters out lower peaks.

Comment: OK, you're the man. Have a good one. Good luck to you in the future.

Comment: @Randy Casburn I said 'hardest part' not hard. :) Not sure how you want to adjust the question. I guess it's a bit long so people just skim over it.

Comment: @Randy Casburn Yeah you're right it is long. I kept adding more to try and make it more clear but stackoverflow tends to work at lightning speed. I often get an answer only seconds after posting a question. :) I'll have a think how to rewrite it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on everything we discussed and I see from your comments, I think the following should work out for you. Basically just iterate over the points and check if the current point is greater than both the previous point and the next point - we can consider those points "peaks":

```js
function getPeaks(points) {
  let prev;
  let next;
  return points.filter((curr, idx, arr) => {
    if (idx > 0) {
      prev = arr[idx - 1];
    }
    if (idx < (arr.length - 1)) {
      next = arr[idx + 1];
    }

    if (prev) {
      if (prev > curr) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    if (next) {
      if (next > curr) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  });
}
const points = [939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424, 506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915, 1276, 1532, 1359, 985, 2182, 2407, 2103, 2392, 2294, 765, 1195, 1537, 1409, 858, 1971, 2214, 1311, 1326, 1383, 1231, 1141];

console.log(getPeaks(points));
```

I compared the resulting array to Randy's chart and the data seems to match up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

why not to keep it simple?

```
var arr = [1,6,4,3,9,11];

var peaks = arr.sort((a, b) => a - b).reverse();
```

the output is:
[11, 9, 6, 4, 3, 1]

then:

```
var top5 = peaks.slice(0,5);
```

and the result is:
[11, 9, 6, 4, 3]

or the whole code for your mather:

```
const peaks1 = [939, 1301, 253, 1380, 1037, 2279, 2462, 2193, 2121, 1424, 506, 2411, 2456, 2295, 915, 1276, 1532, 1359, 985, 2182, 2407, 2103, 2392, 2294, 765, 1195, 1537, 1409, 858, 1971, 2214, 1311, 1326, 1383, 1231, 1141];
const peaks2 =  [1365, 1324, 1013, 1220, 1259, 2204, 2212, 1938, 1882, 1545, 1236, 2090, 2614, 1949, 1307, 1628, 1780, 1263, 1184, 2184, 1411, 1306, 2010, 2057, 1339, 1624, 2480, 2575, 2425, 2617, 2479, 1929, 1805, 1869, 1341, 1104, 2195, 1661, 1174, 1447, 1761, 1362, 1430];
const peaks = [peaks1, peaks2];
function getPeaks(arr){
    let peaks = [];
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        let currPeak = arr[i].sort((a, b) => a - b).reverse().slice(0,1)[0];
        peaks.push(currPeak);
    }
    return peaks.sort((a, b) => a - b).reverse();
}
let result = getPeaks(peaks);
```

and the result vould be:
[2617, 2462]

Answer (score 0):

The solution below has a runtime of O(n):

```
// steps
// loop through array
// on each element
// if element is greater than the element on left
// take note of index
// if element is greater than element on right
// and pos is not default value
// add pos to positions and add value to peaks


function pickPeaks(arr) {

    // assign pos to default value
    let pos = -1

    // create output which will be returned later
    const result = { pos: [], peaks: [] }

    // loop through array
    for (let index = 1; index < arr.length; index += 1) {

        let left = arr[index - 1]
        let element = arr[index]

        // on each element
        // if element is greater than the element on left
        if (element > left) {

            // take note of index
            pos = index
        }

        // if element is greater than element on right
        // and pos is not default value
        if (left > element && pos != -1) {

            // add pos to positions and add value to peaks
            result['peaks'].push(arr[pos])
            result['pos'].push(pos)
            // reset pos
            pos = -1
        }
    }

    // return result
    return result['peaks']
}
```